# How do I guarantee a single session?

Tags: java, jsessionid

I need to **prevent** the situation where either 
1. Two different JSESSIONID's exist for the same user account or,
2. Two tabs of a single browser reference the same JSESSIONID.

Any suggestions?  If an existing session is detected, the user can either:
a) Quit the second attempt
b) Kill the existing session (an assassin!) and start a new session.

The preference is for a sever-side solution.  That is, I don't want to depend on user's turning cookies off which forces the JSESSIONID into the URL.

Comment: Any particular reason to make the user incapable of using different tabs for your application?

Comment: Wait so some web devs want to annoy me by design? I always thought that was more a byproduct of careless design.

Comment: It is not an application that takes advantage of multiple tabs and users can mess up state by reading P1 in one tab, P1 in a second, answering P1 in either triggering P2 but then re-answering P1 in the other.  We just want to enforce a single session for each user.

Comment: @Mike That's something else, there seem to be other solutions to this problem though. One idea from the top of my head: Add a "modifier count" to the session and send it back with requests. If a sensible request comes with an old count, deny it or something. That still allows the use of tabs for most situations (i.e. keeping tabs open to have some additional information available on one glance), but should avoid messing up state.

Comment: These are the types of questions I'm glad I always push for a stateless communication type of architecture.

Comment: There is a COTS back, backend (once removed) involved that isn't completely stateless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part 1 could be done using a singleton pattern that checks current sessionid for the user against a map of user-SID.

Part 2, which could be understood in transactional webapps where you need to ensure that the user reads the correct info (instead of having a one tab with old values and one tab with newer values- scenario)... it could use the same sessionid map, injecting it in the dom and validate it using javascript.

EDIT. Part 2 validation could be done better in a filter against the map of client-sessionid. And a correct definition of the object guarantees that a true unique singleton instance exists.

Comment: The lead architect replied with the following:

Comment: "Part 1: Singletons are notoriously bad solutions in Java EE containers. Singletons should never have state in a Java EE container, because true singletons do not exist in these containers (because multiple class loaders exist). This singleton requires state (map of session IDs). Of course there are way around this, but this may be very expensive in this case.

Part 2: The solution here again uses a client-side solution handling session information (Javascript).

These “work-around” solutions tend to have negative side-effects. "

Comment: Singletons are not a silver bullet and are hard to debug/test due to their nature. And a pattern is not bad by itself but used without careful thinking. About the handling session information, well, jsessionid is ALREADY on client side (the cookie, right?) and the VALIDATION itself could -should- be done on multiple layers given the fact we keep the singleton on server side. If you don't want JS to do the job, even better, use a filter! -- Last: yes, multiple classloaders exist, but they are smart enough to avoid multiple instances of the very same object unless we override it.

Answer (score 1):

Embeding a hidden `input` field with a unique token in each page sounds like the only solution for a problem like this.  This seems to be like the only way to tell one tab from another, even if they're the exact same URL.

Keep in mind though, that what you're doing seems like pretty bad practice; any particular reason to prevent the user from using more than one tab?